# Running Xmpp punjab and twisted on Windows

Tags: xmpp, twisted

I installed openfire, punjab, and twisted (with its dependencies) and i have also done all necessary setting for proxy now when i got to http://localhost/httpbind i get "503 Service Unavaliable"

I want to do two things :

1. Get rid of this error.
2. And how to know twisted and punjab is running and how to restart it???

Comment: I think this question is broad enough and sufficiently lacking in detail that it will be very difficult for anyone to provide a useful answer.  I suggest trying to narrow down the problem a bit, or providing more details about what you did.

Comment: I am having openfire server.

I installed python2.7, latest punjab, and twisted. I am not able to run punjab. How to know that punjab is running on windows???

Comment: I solved the above : 1) by Proxy settings 2) by going to scripts folder of python and running this command twistd.py -y punjab.tac

Answer (score 0):

did you setup Reverse Proxy on IIS? what version of IIS are you using?
if its IIS7 then follow these instructions to setup Reverse Proxy for HTTPBinding

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/659/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing/